# How to register a class instead of creating a xib for a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a custom UITableView that I'm adding programmatically to my UIView.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

  // This line fails on me
  cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ParentCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
```

My `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` method crashes my app because I have not added a xib file, let alone set its identifier as "ParentCell".

But I'd rather stay away from using the storyboard for this, and I was wondering if it was possible to accomplish this programmatically in my `UITableView`.

This is my `viewDidLoad` code where I instantiate my `tableView`

```
var tableView = UITableView()

tableView.frame      = CGRectMake(0, 250, self.view.frame.width, 300)
tableView.delegate   = self
tableView.dataSource = self
containerView.addSubview(tableView)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This is all documented in the [Table View Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this in viewDidLoad method of your view controller.

```
tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "ParentCell")
```